# How to get and set cookie when consuming ASMX service from Java

Tags: java, web-services, cookies, soap, asmx

I'm new to Java, what I'm trying to accomplish is to provide some sort of "session" between Java client and ASMX web-service.

Using wsimport.exe and wsdl I managed to generate a bunch of classes for proxy interaction, web methods are called, and I can get response as predifined class "WebResponse".

I pass Login and Password parameters in SOAP, the service returns OK status from login method. But when I invoke other methods, I get access denied. When I do the same in chrome, it works fine.

I guess I have to extract cookies from generated inherited objects like "Provider"(service), "ProviderSoap" somehow and set it again for next request.

Any advice would be helpful, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You check the SOAP response of the login operation. What are all the values you are getting in the response? You need to see what the the  contains and what  contains. Because the service may use a token in the soap header.

Comment: Thank you. I could get all required data from HTTP headers through BindingProvider. It provides associated context objects for request and response message.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with this code.

```
    ProviderService service = new ProviderService ();
    ProviderSoap soap = service.getPort(ProviderSoap.class);
    soap.login("Administrator", "");

    Map<String, List<String>> map = (Map<String, List<String>>) 
         ((BindingProvider)soap).getResponseContext().get(MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS);
    String cookieParams = "";
    List<String> cookies = map.get("Set-Cookie"); 
    if (cookies != null) {
        StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();
        for (String type : cookies) {
            strBuf.append(type);
        }
        cookieParams = strBuf.toString();
    }

    ((BindingProvider)soap).getRequestContext().put(
                MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS,
                Collections.singletonMap("Cookie", Collections.singletonList(cookieParams)
                )
            );

    response = soap.isSessionEstablished();
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.Context.Request.Cookies` works for me in a class that inherits from `System.Web.Services.WebService`